# Can't find files in production using `fast-glob` and `process.cwd()` with dynamic route segment

Tags: next.js, mdx, next.js13, nextjs-dynamic-routing

I have a `blog` page living under `app/[locale]/home/blog/page.tsx`.

```
import glob from 'fast-glob'
import path from 'path'

const BlogPage = async () => {
  let pages = await glob('**/*.mdx', {
    cwd: `${path.resolve()}/app/[locale]/home/blog`,
  })

  return (
    <></>
  )
}

export default BlogPage
```

The pages array bring the information for my `mdx` files under `app/[locale]/home/blog/**/*.mdx`. It does fetch my blog pages in **development**, but it **DOES NOT** find the pages in production. The pages array just comes empty `{ pages: [] }` if i `console.log({ pages })`, but i get them in development.

I did try to escape the brackets in `app/\[locale\]/...` but didn't work. I trie also using `process.pwd()` and also `path.resolve()` and neither of those worked.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem, but instead of `fast-glob` library i used `glob`.

I think they both use regex under the hood, so instead of escaping `app/\[locale\]/...` like this, you need to use double backslashes. Like this `app/\\[locale\\]/...`. This solved it for me.

Here's [explanation](https://javascript.info/regexp-escaping#:%7E:text=To%20use%20a%20special%20character,called%20%E2%80%9Cescaping%20a%20character%E2%80%9D.)

Comment: Hey, thank you for your response! I'll give it a try and i'll let you know!